# Multiple NICs on Google Cloud Platform VM with site-to-site VPN access on one NIC and external Internet on second NIC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, site-to-site-vpn, gcp

Hello community hoping you can help.

Background:  we have a Web app running on CentOS/Rocky that needs to be accessible with low-latency from different regions:  US East and West Coasts.  We maintain an on-prem datacenter on the West coast and have a GCP presence on the East Coast for serving regionally-close clients faster.  Our source of truth is the West Coast on-prem with replication over a VPN tunnel used extensively for use in the smaller GCP network.

Our application relies on having a backhaul data plane for accessing databases and propagating local caches, with servers using the physical `NIC0` for this backhaul network.  We separate public Internet access onto a different network utilizing a physically separate `NIC1` on each server so that cache propagation does not interfere with public Internet requests.

For the East Coast, we are using GCP and have created a VPC named `prod-vpc1` that allows GCP VMs to access our backhaul data plane located on-prem utilizing the GCP HA Cloud VPN service, with each GCP VM having this VPN network routed through `NIC0` which is on `prod-vpc1`.  We additionally created a separate VPC named `public-traffic-vpc-1` so that each VM's `NIC1` on this separate network is specifically used to service public Internet requests.  The idea behind this configuration is to have an analogous configuration with our on-prem network where we keep backhaul and public Internet traffic separate.

With our current configuration, we have communication between GCP and on-prem via the HA VPN working.  However, due to GCP's way of configuring default routes, public Internet requests are going through `NIC0` which is also where VPN traffic is routed.  We are trying to figure out a way to get public Internet routing to go through `NIC1` while all other backhaul and local VPC communication (ie, other VMs within this East Coast VPC) communicating through `NIC0`.

Below are some networking configuration notes:

1. On-prem backhaul network: `192.168.100.0/22`, with a target server
   having IP `192.168.100.50`.
2. VPC `prod-vpc1` network: `10.202.10.0/24`, gateway IP `10.202.0.1`, routing to `192.168.100.0/22` through VPN tunnel
3. VPC `public-traffic-vpc-1` network: `10.10.12.0/24`, gateway IP `10.10.12.1`
4. GCP HA Cloud VPN configured with BGP, with routing for destination of on-prem network `192.168.100.0/22` as shown in screenshot below.
5. The site-to-site VPN gateway IP is `10.202.10.1`, where the VM's `NIC0` forwards traffic to in order to access on-prem `192.168.100.0/22`

[image]

GCP VM1 configuration and current behavior:

1. `NIC0` on `prod-vpc1 network` with IP `10.202.10.2`
2. `NIC1` on `public-traffic-vpc-1` with IP `10.10.12.2`
3. GCP assigns default route to go through `NIC0` to gateway IP `10.202.10.1`
4. VM1 is able to ping on-prem server `192.168.100.50` and vice-versa through `NIC0`
5. VM1 egress Internet traffic goes through `NIC0`

What we want:

1. VM1 is able to ping on-prem server `192.168.100.50` and vice-versa through `NIC0`
2. VM1 egress Internet traffic goes through `NIC1`

What we've tried:

We manually deleted the default route on `prod-vpc1` that GCP assigns to `NIC0` and then added `public-traffic-vpc-1`'s gateway IP `10.10.12.1` via `NIC1` as the default route.  While this works for directing egress Internet traffic through `NIC1`, we lose access to on-prem (`192.168.100.0/22`) through `NIC0`'s VPN connection.  To address this, on the VM we tried adding a route through `NIC0` for the target on-prem network `192.168.100.0/22`, but get the following error:  `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`.  Obviously `NIC0` does not have an IP on `192.168.100.0/22`, but this same configuration works on-prem where a server NIC on a network is able to communicate with another server over VPN even though that NIC does not have an IP on the remote network.

Comment: Can you provide the following information

* What is the type of cloud vpn you are using (classic/ HA)

* Have you tried by creating routes inside the vm for diverting the traffic

* also have you checked this document 
  
  [https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/tutorials/configure-vpn-between-onprem-cloud](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/tutorials/configure-vpn-between-onprem-cloud)